# Is it possible to keep custom PCM loudness level? What resets it to 100 all the time?

Tags: hda-intel

Can it be done or not? If yes, then how?

Comment: Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is on-topic here. Regards,

Comment: @blueXrider This is not really an open-ended question. It's asking about how to keep a volume setting the same.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you can set the volume using this command

```
amixer set Master 50%
```

therefore just add this to your startup applications and the volume will be set to your desired level whenever you log in.